# how to make boxplot of specific row with group of sample in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, boxplot, errorbar

I am a new baby in R, I would like to ask for help to make the boxplot with the group I have 2 files, file 1 is the value of the samples (gene expression) test.txt

| gene | group1.1 | group1.2 | group2.1 | group2.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 12 | 13 | 12 | 12 |
| a2 | 2 | 3 | 25 | 31 |
| a3 | 24 | 30 | 34 | 22 |
| a4 | 10 | 11 | 23 | 24 |

and file 2 is the sample design design.txt

| file | condition |
| --- | --- |
| group1.1 | group1 |
| group1.2 | group1 |
| group2.1 | group2 |
| group2.2 | group2 |

I want to make the boxplot in R with one specific row for example: a1 and have 2 groups 1, and 2; the output looks like boxplot-a1

How can I do this, direct from 2 files? I think I do the stupid way

```
dt1 <- read.delim("test.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)
dg <- read.delim("design.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)
```

I make the new file by copy and transpose:

| gene | name | group | expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | Group1.1 | group1 | 12 |
| a1 | Group1.2 | group1 | 13 |
| a1 | Group2.1 | group2 | 12 |
| a1 | Group2.2 | group2 | 12.5 |
| a2 | Group1.1 | group1 | 2 |
| a2 | Group1.2 | group1 | 3 |
| a2 | Group2.1 | group2 | 25 |
| a2 | Group2.2 | group2 | 31 |

```
    dt <- read.delim("test_t.csv", sep="\t", header = TRUE)

    a1 <- dt[dt$gene %in% "a1",]
    ggplot(a1, aes(x=a1$group, y=a1$expression)) + 
       labs(title = "Expression A1", x = "Group", y = "Expression") +
       stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.15) + 
        geom_boxplot()
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This is a great place to start with R and plotting https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will practice more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having such data, it is worth first converting the variables of the chr type to factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
  gene  name    group   expression
a1  Group1.1    group1  12
a1  Group1.2    group1  13
a1  Group2.1    group2  12
a1  Group2.2    group2  12.5
a2  Group1.1    group1  2
a2  Group1.2    group1  3
a2  Group2.1    group2  25
a2  Group2.2    group2  31") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    gene = gene %>% fct_inorder(),
    name = name %>% fct_inorder(),
    group = group %>% fct_inorder()
  )
```

Now you can make a boxplot for one value of the `gene` variable

```
df %>% filter(gene == "a1") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gene, expression))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Either for both values at once

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(gene, expression, fill=gene))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much Marek Fiołka